# How to tell IntelliJ to ignore SVN and use git only?

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea

I have a project that is a Git repository as well as a SVN working directory.

I worked on such a thing before with IntelliJ IDEA and I could use Intellij to control the Git repository and used Tortoise for SVN stuff.

Now I switched machines, and had to setup everything from scratch. When I openend the project in IntelliJ it was only a SVN working directory, which was detected.

I made it a git repository again, but IntelliJ doesn't take notice and ignores all things Git.

How can I reverse the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Finally found the help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/changing-vcs-associations.html?origin=old_help):

> To change the version control system associated with a directory
>
> 1. Open the Version Control settings page. This settings page displays a table of directories with associated version control systems.
> 2. In the table, locate the row that corresponds to the directory which you want to put under another version control system.
> 3. Click the VCS column. From the drop-down list that appears, select a new version control system.
> 4. Click OK to save the new mapping and close the Version Control dialog box.